# Order by geometry columns

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am wondering how it really works, I mean "order by" statement when it comes to geometry/geography columns in postgis/postgresql. Besides that really need a way gather rows from a table with a point geometry column with "left" direction. Suppose we have the coastline from an island on a table where each row represents a point on the island coastline, is it possible to select all the points with a query like that?

select * from island_table order by ?

Comment: If you are asking how can you sort by the left-most x coordinate of each polygon, I have posted an answer. Otherwise, could you please clarify.

Comment: If you order by geometry it's ordered alphabetically.

Comment: What does "a point geometry column with "left" direction" mean?

Comment: The problem is that a have points of the coastline of an island and i want to sort them by direction (stating of a north point, complete the circle and probably even draw the linestring)

Comment: So, you want to do this from the most Northerly point going in a clockwise direction? That isn't what your question says. Can you please edit your question. It is not at all clear what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure a natural ordering really exists for a geometry, given that it is two-dimensional and can start from any point in its outer linear ring. However, to answer the second part of your question, the following will order by the left-most x coordinate of every geometry.

```
Select * from island_table order by ST_XMin(ST_Envelope(geom));
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by MikeT, the call to ST_Envelope is superfluous, as the bounding box is available anyway to any indexed geometry, so it is sufficient just to write:

```
Select * from island_table order by ST_XMin(geom);
```

[ST_Envelope](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) gives you the bounding box, from where you can access the minimum and maximum values of x and y, using [ST_XMin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_XMin.html), [ST_YMin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_YMin.html), [ST_XMax](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_XMax.html), etc.

I just did a quick test on some test polygons and if you sort by the WKT representation of a geometry,

```
Select * from island_table order by ST_AsText(geom);
```

you get something like,

`POLYGON((100.00,.....`

`POLYGON((101.86,.....`

`POLYGON((102.17,.....`

`POLYGON((11.82,.....`

that is in text search order.

Whereas if you search by the geometry itself, that is,

```
Select st_astext(geom) from island_table order by geom;
```

it sorts by actual values of the first x coordinate in the geometry, eg,

`POLYGON((11.82,.....`

`POLYGON((100.00,.....`

`POLYGON((101.86,.....`

`POLYGON((102.17,.....`

Neither of these are guaranteed to give you the left-most x coordinate, as the start point is not guaranteed to be left mest, so you are better off using `order by ST_XMin(ST_Envelope(geom))`

Comment: ST_Envelope is unnecessary overhead; ST_XMin and related `box3d` functions will directly access the geometry's bounding box from a spatial index (if available) or other means